# How do I delete a branch I don't need anymore in git?

Tags: git, github, repository, branch, branching-and-merging

I have the `master` branch and then a branch called `feature1` I have a subbranch for `feature1` called `feature2`. I have merged the branches and I'm wondering whether it's a good idea to delete `feature2` because when there will be multiple branches I will be confused about all of the branches? Why aren't branches deleted automatically when merging them? How do I delete a branch both locally and from github?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+delete+branch

Answer (score 1):

An article explaining how to do it: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely/

This answer in so also explains it really well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/10691892

Gist of it:

```
$ git push -d <remote_name> <branch_name>
$ git branch -d <branch_name>
```